# Mount samba filesystem into RHEL 5.5

Tags: mount, file-sharing, server-message-block, redhat

How can I mount windows share file system into RHEL?

I'm not a sysadmin, but I got this task assigned :(

I've tried  this [solution](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/mounting-samba-share-11439/)

```
mount -t smbfs -o username=samba,password=samba //Desktop/Public /mnt/public
```

But the output is:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'smbfs'
```

How can I mount a windows share into RHEL 5?

FWIW I've successfully created a link with the menu: `Places>Connect to Server>Service Type:Windows Share`

Which creates a link in the desktop, but I would need to programatically save files in that machine, hence I need it mounted as filesystem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samba client programs, including smbmount are not installed by default, so you will need to install them first.

```
yum install samba-client
```

Comment: +1 oops, I just noticed this trial version is not registered with RHN :P  This is a test environment :(  Is there a way to connect without those tools? For instance the way `Places>Connect toServer>ServiceType:Windows Share` does?

Comment: Not in any meaningful way. Connecting to the share through the Gnome interface uses the gvfs, which is a different subsystem with its own libraries.